# git commit error saving vimfiles

Tags: git, vim

I am following the easy git guide at [nettuts easy git guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-version-control-with-git/)

I initialised an empty git instance in my `~/` directory and then added my `.vimrc` and my `.vim/` files.

```
git add .vimrc
git add .vim
```

However when I do the `git commit` command I end up with what seems unrelated error messages.

```
sayth@linux-kt34:~> git commit
Error detected while processing /home/sayth/.vimrc:
line  203:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: py << EOF
line  204:
E492: Not an editor command: import os.path
line  205:
E492: Not an editor command: import sys
line  206:
E492: Not an editor command: import vim
line  207:
E15: Invalid expression: 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
line  224:
E171: Missing :endif
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I press enter I get taken to a file. What am I doing wrong with this.

EDIT: have removed virtualenv ref from `.vimrc`. Never noticed the error because i was using gvim which never dislpayed the error.

Comment: This problem is related with you /home/sayth/.vimrc. Paste it so we can comment

Comment: my vimrc is probably too long to paste here. Edit above I removed the offending virtualenv section from the vimrc

Comment: You can past your `.vimrc` to e.g. https://gist.github.com and link to it.

Comment: for reference my vimrc is here https://github.com/flebber/MyVim/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: For reference, I had this problem (errors when vim started from git, but not normally) on a server, although not python related. I was getting errors about "no mouse support", "cannot find colour scheme", etc. This was because the (oldish) system was running Vim 7.0, and so I had compiled vim 7.3 in my home directory, and was using that. Git, on the other hand, appears to use the system vim (confimed by checking `:version`). This is pretty annoying. It can be fixed by forcing git to use your self-compiled version: `git config --global core.editor '~/bin/vim'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `git commit` without specifying a commit message on the command line, it will launch an editor (in your case `vim`) so that you can enter one.  Those errors that you see are from `vim`, reporting that you have errors in your `.vimrc` file.  You should get the same errors if you just launch `vim` normally.

Comment: Removed section from vimrc, then comitted with                git commit -am 'first commit' which seems to have worked.

Comment: I'm getting vim errors that I *don't* get if I launch vim normally. Both occur inside a function declaration - as if it's attempting to execute the function, even though my vimrc never calls it. Is it possible that git is calling a different Vim that somehow doesn't support functions? Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 3):

Your vim installation does not have python support. If you run the command

```
vim --version | grep python
```

you should see `+python`, otherwise it means python is missing from the vim installation.

Comment: sayth@linux-kt34:~> vim --version | grep python
 +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile -python -python3 +quickfix

Answer (score 2):

This happens because git commit choose the editor 'vi'.
You can setting it to use 'vim', with command:

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

More detials can be found [here]:[How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)